# How to inspect local variables of method compiled with no debugging info?

Tags: java, debugging

I want to debug the ArrayList.addAll() method.

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```

I can see the argument in "variables view" of eclipse as arg0. 
Is there a way to see local variables, without recompiling the class with "javac -g".

Comment: You can `print()` to the screen the contents of the ArrayList **before** and **after** calling `addAll()`. It's the poor man's debugger.

Comment: this won't print the local variables of the method.

Comment: I'm talking about iterating on the ArrayList, and `System.out.println()` the values to the screen ;)

Comment: See the update, I want to inspect the value of "numNew". print() won't print the value of "numNew".

Comment: You can't.  Best you can do is observe the effect of branches and calculations, and derive a (range of) value for `numNew`.  The call to `ensureCapacityInternal()` looks like a good candidate.